# Package depends on mpich, cannot be installed because nothing provides libmpi.so.12

Tags: fedora, rpm, packaging

I have some software that uses MPI. I have created an RPM package from that.

The requirements are such that `mpich` and `mpich-devel` are included:

```
BuildRequires:  libstdc++-devel autoconf gcc-c++ automake qmp qmp-devel environment-modules mpich-devel
BuildRequires:  libxml2-devel
Requires:       libstdc++ libxml2 qmp environment-modules mpich
```

([full spec file](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/home:martinueding/qdpxx/qdpxx.spec?expand=1))

When I then try to install that via my Open Build Service home project, it tells me that the required library is not available:

```
# LC_ALL=C dnf install qdpxx qdpxx-devel --refresh --allowerasing
Error: nothing provides libmpi.so.12()(64bit) needed by qdpxx-1.44.0.git131-16.1.x86_64
```

The library is installed on my system, albeit not in a default path:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/
insgesamt 2780
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      13 31. Mär 2016  libfmpich.so -> libmpifort.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      12 31. Mär 2016  libmpichcxx.so -> libmpicxx.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      13 31. Mär 2016  libmpichf90.so -> libmpifort.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       9 31. Mär 2016  libmpich.so -> libmpi.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 31. Mär 2016  libmpicxx.so -> libmpicxx.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 31. Mär 2016  libmpicxx.so.12 -> libmpicxx.so.12.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  134088 31. Mär 2016  libmpicxx.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 31. Mär 2016  libmpifort.so -> libmpifort.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 31. Mär 2016  libmpifort.so.12 -> libmpifort.so.12.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  228128 31. Mär 2016  libmpifort.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 31. Mär 2016  libmpi.so -> libmpi.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 31. Mär 2016  libmpi.so.12 -> libmpi.so.12.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2474552 31. Mär 2016  libmpi.so.12.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       9 31. Mär 2016  libmpl.so -> libmpi.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       9 31. Mär 2016  libopa.so -> libmpi.so*
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096  5. Dez 18:08 pkgconfig/
```

What is missing? How do I get the package to recognize that `mpich` indeed provides the library `libmpi.so.12`?

---

```
$ rpm -q --provides mpich
libmpi.so.12()(64bit)(mpich-x86_64)
libmpicxx.so.12()(64bit)(mpich-x86_64)
libmpifort.so.12()(64bit)(mpich-x86_64)
mpi
mpich = 3.2-6.fc25
mpich(x86-64) = 3.2-6.fc25
mpich2 = 3.2
```

Comment: Is there a `rpm` file that `libmpi.so.12` exists in? (That is, is there a RPM that *provides* that according to the RPM specifications?)

Comment: The package `mpich-3.2-6.fc25.x86_64` contains the file `/usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpi.so.12`.

Comment: Okay, what does `rpm -q --provides mpich` show as that package providing?

Comment: I have added that to the end of the question. Seems like it is contained in there.

Comment: Hmm, can you manually `rpm -i qdpxx...` to see if it's RPM or dnf being derpy?

Comment: For one, the Requires on "libstdc++ libxml2" are no good practice - Requires on library packages are recognised automatically and should not be added explicitly. For the actual issue, what do you get by `rpm -q --whatprovides 'libmpi.so.12()(64bit)'` as those tokes are only exact matches and your mpich package does not provide `libmpi.so.12()(64bit)` as a literal match currently. You may need to take a look at the objdump output for /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.0 and compare that to the output of the script generating the automatic requires during package creation of qdpxx.

Comment: Regarding the automatic dependency generation, you may want to take a look at e.g. http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html
Although I'm not sure if the find-requires and find-provides are located in /usr/bin, it could be that they are under /usr/lib/rpm/ but should be easily checkable when you look at the macros via `rpm --showrc|grep find`or so.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [packaging guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/MPI/):

> MPI implementation specific files MUST be installed in the directories used by the used MPI compiler ($MPI_BIN, $MPI_LIB and so on).

For mpich, binaries must be in `/usr/lib64/mpich/bin`.